# Why can a closed, bounded interval be uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

From what I have read, all finite sets are countable but not all countable sets are finite. As I understand it,

- Countably Finite --- a one to one map onto $\Bbb{N}$ with a limited number of members
- Countably Infinite --- a one to one map onto $\Bbb{N}$ with an unlimited number of members but that you can count in principle if given an infinite amount of time
- Uncountably Infinite --- there is no one to one mapping onto $\Bbb{N}$. Even if you count, you will miss some of the members. And it is infinite.

From this I gather that countable is not the same as finite. Countable is the one to one property with $\Bbb{N}$. Finite just means a limited number of elements.

Now consider $[0,1]$ which is closed and bounded.

- Bounded --- $\forall k \in [0,1]$ we have $k \leq 1$. Similarly all $k\geq0$.
- Closed --- it contains the endpoints $0$ and $1$

Yet I read $[0,1]$ is uncountably infinite. So clearly, neither closure nor boundedness implies finiteness or countability.

**Question:**

Why can a closed, bounded interval be uncountable?

It just seems like something that is bounded would be "more finite" than something that isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving $(0,1) $ is not countable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123352/proving-0-1-is-not-countable)

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: @AsafKaragila If something was finite, I would expect it to be countable. So I just thought a closed bounded interval might somehow be more countable than an unbounded one, but it seems that is not the case.

Comment: Why is $[0,1]$ finite?

Comment: @AsafKaragila as I rather clumsily stated, I have read it isn't and that must be true. But intuitively it just seemed like $[0,1]$ must have fewer numbers than $\Bbb{R}$ because $\Bbb{R}$ contains $[0,1]$ but also has a bunch of other numbers. Doesn't that suggest it is smaller (ie has fewer members)? If I can measure something and tell it is smaller, doesn't that mean it is countable? So maybe I don't mean more finite. Maybe I mean more countable.

Comment: @StanShunpike $\{2,4,6,8,\dots\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ have the same amount of elements, but the latter contains the former. (They have the same amount, because there is a _bijection_, or a one-to-one correspondence, between them. That one-to-one correspondence is $x\mapsto x/2$.)

Comment: Well, $\Bbb N\setminus\{2\}$ has less elements than $\Bbb N$ itself. But there's clearly "the same number of elements" in both sets. Infinity is weird. Infinite sets defy the finite intuition you gained in your physical experience. That's why we have explicit definitions, and that's why we work with them carefully.

Comment: Here's an interesting exercise: Find a bijection between the open intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. (I have a simple answer in mind.)

Comment: We might consider that the idea of $[0,1]$ is handled by *compactness*, not *finiteness*.

Comment: @columbus8myhw $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @StanShunpike Yup. And it's not a big step from that to show that $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb R$ have the same cardinality. And $[0,1]$ is just two points added to $(0,1)$. Since $2$ plus infinity should be infinity, you'd expect $[0,1]$ to have the same cardinality as $(0,1)$ (and thus the same as $\mathbb R$). (It's actually hard to find a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$, but it exists.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you're conflating two meanings of "finite". Some sets are *finite*, meaning they have only finitely many elements.  An interval like $[0,1]$ is not such a set.  On the other hand, $[0,1]$ has *finite length*, which is a quite different matter.  As the other answers have explained, finite length does not imply finiteness (or even countability) in terms of the number of elements.

Comment: When I take a ruler and measure my height. I am counting the number of inches or centimeters. Isn't that what length is? Counting?

Comment: @StanShunpike You are counting inches, or you are counting centimeters, or (if you're extremely industrious) you might be counting atoms, but you are not counting all the (mathematical) points on the line segment that you are measuring.

Comment: What do mathematicians consider counting in inches to be if it is not counting all the mathematical points on a line segment.

Comment: @StanShunpike A line segment equal to my height would be 78 inches long.  Are you suggesting that the number of points on that line segment is 78? The same line segment is approximately 198 centimeters long. Are you suggesting that the number of points on it is 198? Do you think the segment acquires more points because I choose to measure it in centimeters? How about if I measure it in nanometers? Points, inches, centimeters, nanometers, etc. are different things. Counting one is not at all the same as counting another.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly the interval $[0,1]$ is uncountably infinite; it has the same cardinality as $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and many other sets which are commonly used in mathematics.

However, closed and bounded intervals such as $[0,1]$ *do* have a nice finiteness property called *compactness*: that is, if $\{ U_i \mid i \in I \}$ is any collection of open intervals such that $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i = [0,1]$, then there is a finite subset $J \subseteq I$ such that $\bigcup_{i \in J} U_j = [0,1]$.

This is not true of $(0,1)$, since for instance if we define $U_i = (\frac{1}{i}, 1-\frac{1}{i})$ then $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i = (0,1)$ but no finite subset $J \subseteq I$ has $\bigcup_{i \in J} U_i = (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in some sense you are right. If a set is bounded, that means it has finite volume. If it is not bounded, it means it cannot be contained in any ball of finite volume (does not mean it has infinite volume though, e.g. consider the set of all $(k,0)$ for integer $k$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Note that both finite and countable sets have 0 volume in real space...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect otherwise, when $[0,1]$ contains $0$ and $\frac{1}{a}$ for every $a\in[1,\infty)$? Your intuition probably tells you there are plenty of real numbers bigger than $1$. $[0,1]$ includes a variety of things, like
$$\begin{align*}
0&.10000000000000000\ldots\\
0&.01000000000000000\ldots\\
0&.00100000000000000\ldots\\
&\;\vdots\\
0&.012345678910111213\ldots\\
&\;\vdots\\
&\;\text{random numbers like}\\
0&.235672352435943092\ldots\\
0&.594368239803409420\ldots\\
0&.234796028543203921\ldots\\
0&.824875320985230387\ldots\\
0&.314654363453498344\ldots\\
0&.348657378634864915\ldots\\
0&.120490320289123526\ldots\\
\end{align*}$$
and even if you listed a countably infinite number of such elements, you still wouldn't have gotten them all.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what infinity is. I thought somehow $[0,1]$  might be more infinite somehow.  I once watched a video where the prof had $\Bbb{R}$. And he then said, define $\Bbb{R}^*$ as actually including infinity.  So I wasn't sure if there was some tricky way to define relative amounts of infinity or not.

Comment: The notation $[1,\infty)$ just means
$$\{\text{real numbers $a$ that are $\geq 1$}\}=\{a\in\mathbb{R}:a\geq 1\}$$
The occurrence of the symbol $\infty$ is (in this instance) just a notational convenience that doesn't need any fancy interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of cardinality, $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ are the same (ie they have the same cardinality) because you can find a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$.

As you've noted, this has nothing to do with a set being closed or bounded

Answer (score 0):

Let $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$ be a ***closed interval-segment***. What would happen if it were countable? 
(source: https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~guljas/skripte/MATANALuR.pdf)

Then there would exist a bijection $f:\mathbb N\to[a,b]$. For the sake of understanding, let's treat it like a sequence, just like others have already suggested, and look it as nothing but points. I'll state we want to come to a contradiction according to *the axiom of completeness and Cantor's axiom*. We're dealing with *nested-intervals*.

Range/image of $f$: $$\mathcal R_f=[a,b]=\{f(n):n\in\mathbb N\}$$
Next step: $a=a_1,b=b_1$
$$\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}=\frac{2a_1+2b_2}{4}$$
Two cases:

$(i)$ $f(1)\leq\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}$ & $(ii)$ $f(1)\geq\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}$

Technical computations:
$a_1,b_1\in\mathbb R,a_1<b_1\implies$
$$\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}=\frac{a_1+a_1+2b_1}{4}<\frac{a_1+b_1+2b_1}{4}=\frac{a_1+3b_1}{4}\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
$$\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}=\frac{2a_1+b_1+b_1}{4}>\frac{2a_1+a_1+b_1}{4}=\frac{3a_1+b_1}{4}\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

Now we manipulate with this arbitrary function so as to get nonsense:

$(i)\;\&\;(1),\;\;a_2=\frac{a_1+3b_1}{4},\;b_2=b_1$ $$f(1)\leq\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}\implies f(1)\notin[a_2,b_2]$$
$(ii)\;\&\;(2),\;\;a_2=a_1,\;b_2=\frac{3a_1+b_1}{4}$ $$f(1)\geq\frac{a_1+b_1}{2}\implies f(1)\notin[a_2,b_2]$$
We managed to construct $[a,b]$ s.t. $f(1)\notin[a,b]$ neither in $(i)$ or $(ii)$.
We iterate this for $n\in\mathbb N$ and $$a_{n+1}=a_n\underline{\lor} b_{n+1}=b_n$$ and$$[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\subset[a_n,b_n],f(n)\notin [a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$$
But$$\text{axiom of completeness}\implies\;\;\exists x\in[a,b]\cap[a_n,b_n]=[a_n,b_n]\;\forall n\in\mathbb N$$
and
$$f:\mathbb N\to[a,b]\;\text{is bijective}\implies\;\exists m\in\mathbb N\;s.t.\;f(m)=x$$
But (again) $$f(m)\notin[a_{m+1},b_{m+1}]\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$

Comment: I get confused when you write next step $a = a_1$...why are you taking that step?

Comment: @StanShunpike, I thought I should write that to mark the beginning of my proof, on the other hand, I didn't want any indexes in the first few sentences before the actual proof.