# Proof that the Irrationals are Countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, infinity

Proof: Between any two irrationals lies a rational, by the Density of the rationals in the real number system. There are only countably many rationals; therefore, there are only countably many pairs of irrationals. Therefore the number of irrationals is countable since the cardinality of $2\mathbf{N}$ is $\mathbf{N}$.

I don't know why I came across this logic since I know the irrationals are uncountably infinite, but I don't see the hole in my logic.

Comment: To make this argument work, you'd need a one-to-one correspondence between rational and irrational numbers.  Part of the challenge of finding such a correspondence lies in the fact that between any to irrationals there is not just one rational number, but infinitely many.

Comment: It is true that between any two irrational lies a rational, but the same rational can separate many pairs of irrationals!

Comment: It might help if you try to turn this heuristic into a formal proof and see where it goes wrong. If you are trying to construct a map from the irrationals to the rationals, you should have a hard time ensuring that the mapping is one-to-one.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18969/why-are-the-reals-uncountable

Comment: The basic problem here is surely with your first statement, "Between any two irrationals lies a rational, by the Density of the rationals in the real number system." There is a big difference between "There exists an $x$ such that so-and-so holds of $x$" and "There exists a _unique_ $x$ such that so-and-so holds of $x$". Density allows you to conclude the first, but not the second.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The claim that between two rationals there is only one irrational is false. In fact between two rationals there are many irrationals, so you will have to map *a lot* of irrationals to the same pair (for most pairs too).

Therefore your proof does not constitute of a bijection, or even a well-defined function. This is a common mishap with infinite objects, though. They tend to get very confusing!

Comment: @lhf: Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

To make this argument work, you'd need a one-to-one correspondence between rational and irrational numbers. Part of the challenge of finding such a correspondence lies in the fact that between any to irrationals there is not just one rational number, but infinitely many.