# the interval $[0,1]$ without the rational numbers is not a countable set

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that the interval $[0,1]$ without the rational numbers is not a countable set, but I have to prove it using Lebesgue measure theory! Could anybody help?

Comment: Prove that it's measure is positive. In fact, prove
$$\lambda([0,1] \setminus \mathbb Q) = \lambda([0,1]) = 1$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proof that the irrational numbers are uncountable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732/proof-that-the-irrational-numbers-are-uncountable)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you put $\;A:=\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]\;$ , then $\;m(A)=0\;$ since $\;|A|\le|\Bbb Q|=\aleph_0\;$ , so

$$m([0,1]\setminus A)=m([1,0)]-m(A)=1$$

and thus $\;[0,1]\setminus A\;$ cannot be countable.

Answer (score 1):

The main point is to prove that the measure of a countable set is zero.  Start with the definition of outer measure, and show that for any $\epsilon>0$ that you can construct a collection of intervals $I_n$ whose union contains the countable set, and such that the sum of the measures of the $I_n$ is less than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $[0,1]$ is uncountable but $\mathbf{Q}$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $A\subset B$ are both measurable sets then $$m(B\setminus A)=m(B)-m(A).$$ Recall also that the Lebesgue measure of a countable set is $0$, and the Lebesgue measure of an interval is the length of the interval.